# Assign command output to variable with echo and cut

Tags: bash, loops, process, echo, cut

I have to make a script that compares PIDs and PPIDs to understand who generates who and make an output log like 
"process ... generates process ..."
it's almost done but
I can't get only the PID value to store it into an array and make the comparison because I'm using the command substitution in the wrong way
Thanks to everyone would help me and sorry for the text I'm a beginner of bash and of this place

my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\r\n'
GLOBIGNORE='*'
thispid=$$
ps -opid= -oppid= -ocommand= -c > processi.txt
eval  'array=($(<processi.txt))'
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
pid=$( echo "$i" | cut -d" " -f1 )
echo $pid
done
```

With only the ps command I have an output like this:

```
 618   616 -bash
 2668   618 bash
 629   628 -bash
 1185   629 man
 1186  1185 sh
 1187  1186 sh
 1190  1187 sh
 1191  1190 less
```

My problem is with that part of cut command because this doesn't work:

```
pid=$( echo "$i" | cut '-d" "' '-f1' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using [*process substitution*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) :

```
pids=()
ppids=()

while read pid ppid _; do
    pids+=( $pid )
    ppids+=( $ppid )
done < <(ps -opid= -oppid= -ocommand= -c)

printf '%s\n' "${pids[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${ppids[@]}"
```

Comment: i have tried but only gives me 2 lines of blank output, not works

Comment: Fixed my answer